# jQuery autoAnchors.js plugin post to sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm using [autoAnchors.js](http://fredibach.ch/jquery-plugins/autoanchors.php)

I would like this script to:
  1. Search for H1 tags
  2. Create anchors for these
  3. Post the MENU of these to another div (#sidebar)

Currently the script will do [1](http://fredibach.ch/jquery-plugins/autoanchors.php) and [2], but posts the menu to the top of the same id/class, not a separate one.

Looks like I need to alter the: return this
to post the menu elsewhere.

Any support would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the current script:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.autoAnchors=function(settings){
        var defaults = {
            anchor: 'h2',
            title: '',
            numbering: false
        };
        var s = $.extend(defaults, settings);

        var mcnt = 0;
        this.each( function() {
            mcnt++;

            var links = '<div class="autoanchors">';
            if (s.title){
                links += s.title;
            }
            links += '<ul>';

            var cnt = 0;
            $(this).find(s.anchor).each( function() {
                cnt++;

                var title = $(this).text();
                var filteredtitle = title.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/g,'').replace(/\s/g,'_');

                if (s.numbering){
                    title = '<span class="numbering">'+cnt+'</span>'+title;
                    $(this).html('<span class="numbering">'+cnt+'</span>'+$(this).html());
                }

                links += '<li><a href="#'+mcnt+'.'+cnt+'.'+filteredtitle+'">'+title+'</a></li>';
                $(this).attr("id",mcnt+'.'+cnt+'.'+filteredtitle);
            });

            links += '</ul></div>';

            if (cnt > 0){
                $(this).prepend(links);
            }
        });

        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

I'm currently calling it using:

```
$(".pageMainContent").autoAnchors( 
  {
    anchor: 'h1',
    title: '',
    numbering: false
  }
);
```